# static .gif not appearing after deployment

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services

I have an upload button on my MVC web application which allows a user to upload a file. This file is uploaded onto the system and some `async` actions are made on this file which may take up to 1/2 minutes. When a user presses the upload button, I want the processing.gif to appear until the upload has finished. This works fine locally (when the user hits upload the `.gif` appears until the upload has finished) although when I deploy to `AWS elastic beanstalk` the `.gif` does not appear. Can anyone tell me why?

**Upload View**:

```
 <h4><strong></strong></h4>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
        <div>
            <p><strong>Upload Surveys for @Model.OfficialSchoolName in .PDF format</strong></p>
            <br />

            <form id="upload" class="btn btn-default" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="@Url.Action("Upload", "CompletedCamps")" onsubmit="document.getElementById('loading').style.display='block'">
                <div>
                    <input name="file" type="file" class="btn btn-link" required />
                    <br />
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Import</button>

                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <div style="text-align: center;">
            <img id="loading" src="../../Content/processing.gif" alt="Updating ..." style="display:none;" />
        </div>
        <br />
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**:

```
  [HttpGet] 
        public ActionResult Upload(int? id)
        {
            CompletedCamp completedCamp = db.CompletedCamps.Find(id);
            return View(completedCamp);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file, int? id)
        {
            CompletedCamp completedCamp = db.CompletedCamps.Find(id);

            string filename = Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
            string filepath = Server.MapPath(Path.Combine("~/Surveys/", filename));
            file.SaveAs(filepath);
            await AzureVisionAPI.ExtractToTextFile(filepath);
            ParseSurveyText parse1 = new ParseSurveyText();
            await Task.Run(() => parse1.ParseTextFile(completedCamp.RollNumber, completedCamp.OfficialSchoolName, completedCamp.Date));



            return View();
        }
```

Below is what is shown after the upload button is pressed deployed vs locally

[upload deployed vs local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6vHp.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `img` tag has the `style` attribute with `display:none` value. That is hiding the `processing.gif` It looks like the javascript that should show the `processing.gif` when the form is being submittet has not been deployed with the rest of the code?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry I left out: onsubmit="document.getElementById('loading').style.display='block'" - this displays the .gif when a user presses upload which works perfect locally.

Comment: I have edited my post with a picture showing what is displayed when the upload button is pressed

Comment: On the image you have added I can see that `processing.gif` itself is not found. The `img` tag is there, but it cannot find the gif. You need to specify the right path to the gif in the `src` attribute. Is the gif in the content folder in AWS after deploy?

Comment: What is the easiest way to check the Content folder after deployment?

Comment: That would be to log into the AWS server and find the folder to see if the gif is in it. Are there other images/gifs that are displaying on the site you have deployed to? It could be that you need to change the path `../../Content/processing.gif`. Could it be that the gif is located in another folder on AWS..

Comment: Thanks Orvar, I will check this now

Comment: Hi again Orvar, I have just checked and it seems like the .gif is not in the Content folder when it is deployed. Can you tell me why this is? and how I can fix this issue please?

Comment: How are you deploying the project to AWS, from Visual Studion?